# What does it mean to define a norm as $\|.\|_{A, B}$? (e.g. $\|.\|_{\infty, [-1, 1]}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I have seen when many instances of $\|.\|_{A}$, e.g. $A = \infty$ or $1$, etc. What does it when we write a norm as $\|.\|_{A,B}$?

For example see [theorem 3 of this](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v40/Daniely15.pdf), which uses $\|.\|_{\infty, [-1, 1]}$.

Comment: This mean norm A on a set B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your link: see the paragraph starting with **Notation:** on page 3.